# Installation of ROS - urgent

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we face this problem since about one year and in every Ubuntu installation, it is alway the same (trying Xubuntu, Linux Mint ...):

Persistent problem updating (installing) ROS (Groovy or Hydro):

Using "sudo apt-get upgrade" results **ALWAYS** in:
Fetched 83.4 MB in 8min 33s (163 kB/s)
Failed to fetch [http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-groovy-navigation/ros-groovy-navigation_1.10.3-s1387754744~precise_amd64.deb](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-groovy-navigation/ros-groovy-navigation_1.10.3-s1387754744%7Eprecise_amd64.deb)  Connection failed
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

--> It is NOT a connection problem

I WAS NEVER ABLE TO INSTALL ROS IN A QUIET MODE!!!! I had to fetch manually from http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/

The problem is in the divergence of the real name of a file and the name in the get list.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133476/installation-of-ros---urgent/) by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RedoXyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/12196/redoxyde/) on 2014-02-26**:
That's interesting... I've done Hydro installation on Ubuntu 12.04 32b, and 13.04 64b without facing such problem... It looks like it comes from your network configuration, maybe a caching or filtering proxy, or from your GNU/Linux setup, maybe locales...
Anything unusual on your setup ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-26**:
I'm able to fetch the file you linked to without problems. Are you able to fetch it through your browser or through wget on the machine you're trying to install linux on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes ... maybe the proxy of our company. For example, you have a file naming like this xxxx-12343-+0000-xxxx,deb, you have the result  xxxx-12343- 0000-xxxx,deb (missing +) in some, but not every case. A good idea are the locales, where I may have a look.

In some cases, we are using VMWare images, in one case I installed Linux Mint 13.10 with Hydro on a standalone machine. Ok, Hydro won't work with 13.10 (especially rviz (libogre-dev), but here I can wait until may for the next release.

---

Originally posted by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) with karma: 156 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-26**:
It sounds like your company proxy is rewriting URLS in a way that doesn't play well with the filenames on the ROS package server. I suggest you talk to your local network administrator.